# CodeIgniter Concat

Tags: mysql

I've spent a few hours staring at this piece of code. Fresh eyes please! 
  Here is a shortened version of the query:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL 
server version for the right syntax to use near 
'FROM (`requests` c) JOIN `inventory` d ON `d`.`listing_seq_no` = `c' at line 7


SELECT DISTINCT `c`.`req_id`, `u`.`user_id`, `u`.`org_name`, 
CONCAT_WS(' ', `l`.`strength`, `l`.`unit)` as dos, `c`.`quantity` AS quantity1, 
    (SELECT sum(quantity) from inventory d2 
          WHERE d2.listing_seq_no = c.listing_seq_no 
    ) as inv_total,
 FROM (`requests` c)   
 JOIN `inventory` d 
    ON `d`.`listing_seq_no` = `c`.`listing_seq_no` 
 JOIN `listings` l 
    ON `l`.`listing_seq_no` = `c`.`listing_seq_no`
```

EDIT: Original CodeIgniter Code snippet:

```
$this->db->select ( "c.req_id,
        u.user_id,
        u.org_name,
        l.tradename as name,
        CONCAT_WS(' ', l.strength, l.unit) as dos,
    );
```

Comment: where is the alias 'l' in the concat function coming from?

Comment: oops, that's extraneous, ( I tried to remove as much 'other code' as possible

Comment: @Peter: Not quite following ...

Comment: Thanks guys, I edited the code to display the CodeIgniter code that generated the mysql error... the two answers listed below seem valid... I just am not sure how to solve them in CI.

Comment: Is this the exact code you used? Why does `dosage` result in `dos`?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help... It turns out that Max's last comment was the correct solution.  Bugger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
CONCAT_WS(' ', `l`.`strength`, `l`.`unit)`
```

Should be:

```
CONCAT_WS(' ', `l`.`strength`, `l`.`unit`)
```

Comment: Interesting... not exactly sure why that is occurring (generated from Codeigniter)

Comment: I haven't used CodeIgniter, but my guess would be that a space between `unit` and the bracket might be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

try removing the parens around (`requests` c)

Comment: Same as the comment I posted above

Comment: Michaels comment to my answer (that I deleted): I don't know how to remove the parenthesis, as the original function call was done using CodeIgniter as the framework as: $this->db->from('requests c') ..

Comment: I think Max S. just nailed it.

Comment: Thx guys for looking at this.  I've pasted the CI code that generates the Mysql code -- Not sure how to control the parentheses ...  
The reason I showed only mysql code before is because I thought I could backtrack the issue easier that way...

Comment: yuck. looks like a bug in the CI 'db' class - you could try removing the 'l' aliases inside the concat_ws() to see if it goes away, or use a plain concat(), or adding the backticks yourself in the code.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but you can use:

```
$this->db->select("<your_select_portion>", FALSE);
```

to avoid the auto-quoting feature of the CI DB class. I am a fan of using MySQL functions on select statements with CI, and this usually fixes the problem (except when you start using the query-caching feature, but that's another story).